# How can I find the formula used to produce this number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a game, each character has different attributes with values to them. The attributes are things like Strength and Speed and are graded on a scale of 1-100.

The game uses a formula to produce an overall number. I want to make a program that can use the formula to produce the overall, but I do not know the formula used in the game to produce it. I have 14 examples of attributes and the overall value given.

The Numbers I have -

[image]

In previous games, there were 10 different attributes, the sum of which was divided by 10 with 10 added to the result.

Edit: A friend gave me the formula so I'll just post it here.

((Striking Power+Grappling Power+Durability+Charisma+1)÷8.25)
+
((Submission+Striking Defense+Grappling Defense+Speed+Toughness+1)÷12.25)
+
((Jumping+Agility+Adrenaline+Recovery+Tag Team+2)÷25.25)

Comment: The question as posed is unanswerable. If you want to have a chance at getting the same function used by whatever generated this information, you will need a lot of samples.

Comment: As atomic has stated, without numerous samples, it is impossible to tell. One formula is to add all the numbers and then multiply them by $0$. Then add $91$.

Comment: Hm, [oeis](http://oeis.org/search?q=90%2C+85%2C+80%2C+80%2C+70%2C+75%2C+80%2C+85%2C+85%2C+95%2C+90%2C+80%2C+95&language=english&go=Search) doesn't know the answer:).

Comment: @Antoine Well, I'm willing to bet that the game is just using a PRNG, in which case OEIS will get you zilch.

Comment: I think we have seen this question, with exactly these numbers, long ago, but can't find it.

Comment: Could it really be random? They use the formula for the character attributes and so it's the same across the board, with the rule that the overall can't exceed 100. This means that a player can't have 100 in each category.

Comment: @RamsesBrown In Dennis' comment, PRNG stands for pseudo random number generator. You ask "could it really be random"? The answer is "no, because they use a PRNG". However, for all intents and purposes the answer is "yes", in that you would need a lot of computing power to work out the PRNG and the "seed" being used. If you are really interested in PRNG, you should read the second volume of Donald Knuth's book "The art of computer programming".

Comment: Might perhaps Eureqa be any good here? creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa

Comment: To get the formula, you really should have the game (WWE 13?)  around, change the attributes yourselves and see how does it affect your overall score. In any event, the formula your friend give you is one discovered by trial any error. When in doubt, use the source. If you can't use the source, ask the oracle/google.

Comment: I started a Meta thread about this question. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11152/how-to-approach-an-unanswerable-question). Basically, no matter how big your sample you cannot work out the formula, but one could search in the "real world" for such a solution (not just for this game, but for arbitrary games - do all games which give you attributes have similar formulas?). Lord_Farin points out that this "real world" approach means that MSE isn't the best place for this question. You might want to try, say, [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

It is $5\cdot \mid \det(M_n)\mid$, where $\det(M_n)$ are the numbers of the sequence A071569, from integer sequences, starting with $n=72$, i.e.  -18, 17, -16, 16, -14, 15, \ldots$

Comment: I feel bad for saying that I don't fully understand this. Maybe it's too advanced for me?

Answer (score 0):

If the last time they took the average and added 10, perhaps now they take the average, round down, and add 8.

Comment: I updated my post with a missing number (14 in total, not 13, I apologize), and added a second set of numbers with a different overall.

Answer (score 0):

Two sets are still a thin sample, but this gives you a good result with a similar approach: sum/7.5 - 65

Comment: Your response has been obsoleted by the addition of a dozen more samples.

Answer (score 0):

That particular function could have been discovered by linear regression, although you might have needed a few data points.

In general, reverse engineering a formula from data is a very hard and involved process, requiring lots of experimentation and some amount of experience in interpreting the results. Although sometimes you get lucky and things are simple and don't take much work.